# Don't inherit height and width from `table-cell` or `flex`

Tags: css, tablecell

Is there a way to achieve this whilst being responsive?

[image]

Right now the button inherits the height from the headline (its width also changes). I'd rather not have to set a fixed height on the button, or put it in a wrapper.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/JfnjY/14/

I've tried with both `table`:

```
.container4 {
    display: table;
}
.container4 h1, .container4 .button {
    display: table-cell;
}
.container4 p {
    display: table-row;
}
```

And `flex`:

```
.container1 {
    display: flex;
}
.container1 .button {
    margin-left: auto;
}
.container1 p {
    /* Add something here to make the `p` go below the `h1` */
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many ways of realizing this layout.  Here is one way of doing it.

Consider the following HTML snippets:

```
<div class="container container1">
    <div class="button">Click me</div>
    <h1>Table-cell lipsum</h1>
    <p>This is how I want it, except the button shouldn't inherit any height.</p>
</div>
<div class="container container2">
    <div class="button">Click me</div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
        <h1>Table-cell lipsum</h1>
        <p>This is how I want it, except the button shouldn't inherit any 
           height. Morbi consequat, purus nec suscipit luctus...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```css
.container {
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 20px;
}
.button {
    padding: 5px 17px;
    border: 2px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: right;
}
.container1 h1 {
    background-color: beige;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
.container1 p {
    background-color: pink;
}

.container2 .sub-wrap {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

In both cases, I floated the button to the right and used `display: inline-block` to keep a shrink to fit width/height, and `white-space: nowrap` to keep the text on a single line.

In the first case, `.container1`, I used `overflow: auto` on `h1` to keep the text from interfering with the button.  The `p` will just be in normal flow below the title and button.

In the second case, `.container2`, I wrapped the title and paragraph in a block level element `.sub-wrap` which has `overflow: auto`, that way neither the paragraph nor the title wrap around the button.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Dap4M/

Comment: Real mastery! Thanks Marc Audet. Both solutions are fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JfnjY/15/)**

You can keep the `table-cell` property but don't apply it directly on `button` class, instead make a wrap with `table-cell` & then define your button this way button wont have to apply full height!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container container4">
     <h1>Table-cell lipsum</h1>

    <div class="button-wrap">
        <div class="button">Click me</div>
    </div>

    <p>This is how I want it, except the button shouldn't inherit any height.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container4 h1, .container4 .button-wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

It's a good practice to keep the layout classes separate from the actual elements classes.